# Python редактор формул

Tags: python, математика, latex

Всем привет. Как сделать так, чтобы в Python при вводе с клавиатуры выводились не компьютерные символы, а математические (LaTeX). В консоли можно, либо в IPython (Jupyter Notebook).
Как в консоль вывести LaTeX символы?

Comment: Где вы хотите результат увидеть (в GUI/pdf/ графике)? Для манипуляций формул можно на Sympy посмотреть (модуль умеет и latex выводить).